# My R is fully updated, but I keep getting the error message "Bioconductor version 3.15 requires R version 4.2"

Tags: r

I'm completely new to R, so some help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code I typed in:

```
.bioc_packages <- c("phyloseq", "DESeq2", "microbiome", "metagenomeSeq", "ALDEx2")
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(.bioc_packages, version = "3.9")
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Error: Bioconductor version '3.9' requires R version '3.6'; use `BiocManager::install(version =
  '3.15')` with R version 4.2; see https://bioconductor.org/install
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide the output of `version`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R version 4.1.x you will need to try:

```
BiocManager::install(version = '3.14')
```

Version 3.9 is too old for your version of R, and 3.15 is too new.